# Data Not saved in server

Tags: iphone, ios6

thanks for replying for my question. I got a confidence that i will get some valuable feedback and replies on my query. Please find the below code. this is method which saves data in the server,

```
-(NSMutableString *) saveChanges 
{
    NSMutableString *changes = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSString *completeXml = [[NSString alloc]init];

    for (NSString *key in objectToModify)
    {
        BaseModel *orig = [savedOriginalObject objectForKey:key];
        BaseModel *new = [objectToModify objectForKey:key];

        BaseModel *nested = Nil;

        // BaseModel was added
        if (orig == nil)
        {
            nested = [ModelReferences referenceNested:new];
            nested.EntityState = [[EntityState alloc] initWithIntValue:Added];
            NSMutableString *newXml = [self createObjectToXML:nested];
            completeXml = [completeXml stringByAppendingString:newXml];
        }

        // BaseModel might be modified
        else {
                BaseModel *newNested = [ModelReferences referenceNested:new];
                BaseModel *origNested = [ModelReferences referenceNested:orig];

                NSMutableString *newXml = [self createObjectToXML:newNested];
                NSMutableString *origXml = [self createObjectToXML:origNested];

                completeXml = [completeXml stringByAppendingString:newXml];

                if (![newXml isEqualToString:origXml]) 
                {
                    nested = newNested;
                    nested.EntityState = [[EntityState alloc] initWithIntValue:Modified];
                }

            }

        if (nested != Nil)
            [changes appendString:[self createObjectToXML:nested]];
    }

    //refreshes both dictionaries (objectToModify and savedOriginalObject) 
    [self refreshSavedOriginalObject:completeXml];


    if ([changes length] > 0)
        return changes;
    else
        return Nil;
}
```

when ever i do any changes its getting saved but when i wanted to add a new data or object its not saving in server. for example I wanted to add an object in `NSMutableDictionary`, after adding its not getting saved. Please let me know if i have to provide more information about my coding.

Comment: The fix is.. By generating a UUID for the given Base model, once the UUID is generated, the base model loop will consider it as a not orig and make it as a new UUID and create a location.. Hence The Base model with new UUID will be sent to server and save simultaneously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is.. By generating a UUID for the given Base model, once the UUID is generated, the base model loop will consider it as a not orig and make it as a new UUID and create a location.. Hence The Base model with new UUID will be sent to server and save simultaneously.